# Failed to install postgres 9.3 with postgis on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: postgresql, installation

I am following this guide to install postgres 9.3 on ubuntu 17.10, but after line of code where I actually try to install (sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 pgadmin3) I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package postgresql-9.3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'postgresql-9.3' has no installation candidate
```

Also, I need to install postgis, and when I type

```
 sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
```

I got the same error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm not on ubuntu but just wondering why you need to install such an old version of Postgresql/Postgis, have you got an old dump to restore?

Comment: Because I need to install some extension which only support that version. :/

Comment: oh ok, I would be interested to know what the extension is. Looking at the Postgresql site they certainly have PG 9.3 for ubuntu, but versions are 16.04 and 18.04 so not sure how that relates to your 17.10 its been a long time sine I was in that space. You should add an ubuntu tag to your question as I think it is that area of expertise that is needed. Also simplify the install first just get PG installed then PGadmin and then postgis. I have an old note that says;

    sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 libpq-dev

Add the ubuntu tag and you should get more help

Comment: Why install 9.3 now? It will be end-of-live in the next month. So you are installing a version that will no longer be supported in 4 weeks. You should install a current version, e.g. 10 if you install today

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [postgres wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) I was able to install postgresql-9.3 using their Quickstart steps on ubuntu LTS 18; same should be true for 17 if you want.  fwiw I tend to lay off the odd number installs but I also don't have to worry about that extension you mentioned.